# Collapsing all open folders in sidebar not working when using theme sublime text

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have always used `Ctrl+Alt+LeftClickOnParentFolder` to **collapse all open folders in sidebar in Sublime Text 3**.
This has always worked when using the default theme. When I use a theme this shortcut doesn't work. **Can anyone tell me how to collapse all open folders in sidebar when using a theme in Sublime Text 3**.

Comment: Try doing `Ctrl-Alt-LeftClick` on the arrow just to the left of the folder, or if there's no arrow about two character-widths to the left. You might need to do it a couple times.

Comment: @MattDMo Yeah I used to click on the arrow to the left side of the folder but now it doesn't work even when I do this multiple times.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: @MattDMo Material Theme

Comment: I also used other themes like ayu and it is also not working

Comment: I can confirm the behavior using Adaptive vs. Material, but I can't find anywhere the behavior would be defined or overridden.

Comment: alt-left-click on a folder collapses everything below it in ST4

Comment: Finally! Thank you.